# Reference multiple Parameter Cloudformation AWS

Tags: aws-cloudformation

If I have some parameter like

```
Parameters:

 Owner:
   Description: Enter Team or Individual Name Responsible for the Stack.
   Type: String
   Default: Name

 Project:
  Description: Enter Project Name.
  Type: String
  Default: Whatever
```

is there a way to reference them both like:

```
Resources:

Resource:
  Properties:
    Name: !Ref Owner- !Sub ${Project}
```

merci A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
  Name: !Sub "${Owner}-${Project}"
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c21c28c59b7

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Name: !Join [ '-', [!Ref Owner, !Ref Project] ]
```

Which will generate something like ownerX-projectY